How hide MAUI window?
can you tell me if it is possible to hide the window in MAUI? For example, I want the window containing the MainPage to be hidden when launching the application and a second window for authorization to be displayed. After successful login, the authorization window closes and the main window becomes visible
The root of my question lies in the fact that if I define the MainPage in App.xaml.cs as a LoginPage, then later I cannot reassign it because the setter of this property works only if the MainPage is null. I decided to split the MainPage and LoginPage in different windows and now I want to hide the window containing the MainPage until the user logs in.
The application is planned to be used only under Windows

You can set  the default page as LoginPage, and then call App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage() after successful login. Or you can use NavigationPage and navigate from LoginPage to MainPage after successful login.

Does this answer your question? How can you restrict/control the navigation routes the user can visit based on login status/role?


If I define the MainPage in App.xaml.cs as a LoginPage, then later I
cannot reassign it because the setter of this property works only if
the MainPage is null.

After logging successfully, you can use App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();. Or you can use  MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage()); And then call await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage()); after successful login. For hiding the window, you can refer this AppWindow.Hide Method method;
